# Make jqueryUI slider working on touch screen

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, slider, touch

What I have today is a rails app displaying a slider built with jquery-ui-slider component.

I have installed jquery with

```
yarn install
```

and imported jquery-ui-component in *application.js* as follows:

```
 import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider";
```

When I test my app on mobile device, the drag and drop of slider button doesn't work. I found that it was perfectly normal as jquery doesn't provide touch functionality on premise.

I tried to use jquery.ui.touch-punch.min as follows but it doesn't work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Do I need to upload the source code of touch-punch and put in a file ? If yes where ?

Then I tried to use touchpunch-rails gem without success..

Does It exist any other way to have the touching functionality ?

Comment: Do you able to resolve this issue? @Maximilimen

Comment: I have same issue - touchpunch (i.e. sliding the slider) does not work on mobile devices.  Any solution found yet?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this working as follows.   I removed the touchpunch gem from my Gemfile.  I required this file by: `//= require ./touch_slider/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js`.    I downloaded this .js file from:  https://www.cdnpkg.com/jqueryui-touch-punch/file/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js/.   It worked: I can now slide the sliders on a mobile device.  (Note:  just using the touchpunch gem did not work for me)